HttpContext returning null on Blazor Login page
Last week I was working on my blazor web app .net 8 project and everything was working fine. Now I come back and I can't login anymore. My login page is throwing an error.
Login.razor:
@page "/Account/Login"
@layout EmptyLayout
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using AVAZicht.Components.Layout
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using AVAZicht.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject ILogger<Login> Logger
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager

<PageTitle>Log in</PageTitle>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-lg-4" align="center">

            <img src="images/ava_logo_transp.png" class="w-75 mb-3" />

            <section class="p-0">
                <StatusMessage Message="@errorMessage" />
                <EditForm Model="Input" method="post" OnValidSubmit="LoginUser" FormName="login">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">
                            <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Input.RememberMe" class="darker-border-checkbox form-check-input" />
                            Ingelogd blijven
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Inloggen</button>
                    </div>
                </EditForm>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string? errorMessage;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    private string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        }

    }

    public async Task LoginUser()
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
        }
        else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
                "Account/LoginWith2fa",
                new() { ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl, ["rememberMe"] = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo("Account/Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Error: Invalid login attempt.";
        }
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}


The error I get:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

AVAZicht.Components.Account.Pages.Login.HttpContext.get returned null.


I created a clean Blazor Web App .net 8 project with individual accounts as authentication type and that works just fine. I've gone through every single page it uses, going to the login page.
Anyone any tips?

I removed @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" from <Routes /> and <HeadOutlet /> in the app.razor file and now the login page works again. How does this work? Can't I set a default rendermode?

HttpContext is only available in SSR(Server static render) mode. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor.
The App.razor is to set global rendermode:

<Routes /> means "no interactive", which will be set to SSR.
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode"/> will be set to "SSR (prerender) + interactiveServer"
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)"/> will be set to pure "interactiveServer" without SSR.

So HttpContext is only available when using 1st one (SSR).
If you create a template with "individual auth" and check the App.razor you will find
...
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
...
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}

It is using "dynamic" global mode. If the page route is "/account/..." this page rendermode will be set to null, that equals to SSR. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#area-folder-of-static-ssr-components

Thanks, that works great! What is the best practice regarding prerender true/false? When to use of don't use prerender?

@Jeremy. SSR(prerender) use "Httpcontext".  InteractiveServer use "websocket".  In my opinion, WASM load slowly, so I will consider using prerender for some static page loading quickly.   I prefer to disable prerender when using "InteractiveServer" because it is already fast loading.  But if your mechanism needs httpcontext, you could consider using SSR page, or more straightforward, just create api controller to process your httpcontext related codes.

Official docs are a bit misleading. They say: "... makes use of HttpContext to determine if the component is rendering on the server". However, as you pointed out, HttpContext only determines whether component is interactive or SSR! nothing about interactivity location can be determined from HttpContext.
